# Share cases created by customer community users with the community users of parent account of associated account

Tags: apex, sharing, customer-community, sharerecord

Here is what I am trying to achieve,
[image]
Case OWD is Private.

I want to share cases created by community users with the community users(contacts) of the parent account of the associated account.Sharing sets are an all or nothing.

So I thought about apex sharing and started with writing a small snippet in developer console to test if it works for community users

```
CaseShare share = new CaseShare();
share.CaseId  = '5005B000002giXf';
share.UserOrGroupId = '0055B000000vZ7W';
share.CaseAccessLevel  = 'read';
insert share;
```

But this gave an error

> Line: 5, Column: 1 System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception
>   on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY,
>   insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

Comment: As you mention sharing sets I will assume you are using standard Customer Community licences which do not have access to Apex Sharing.

Comment: @DaveHumm Thanks for your reply. Please update as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: added an answer. I have an idea for a solution but not been able to test it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard Customer Community and Customer Community Login licence types do not support Apex sharing, this means that it would not be possible to share to these users with this method.

I think that by creating a custom lookup field on Case to Account that is populated by a Process Builder with the Child Account Id could allow the use of a sharing set.